# view.getTop() reutrns wrong result

Tags: android, canvas, android-linearlayout, android-view

I have this xml, with the layout surface(which doesnt cover the whole screen):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>




<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/down"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/down"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/down"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/down"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
        android:src="@drawable/up" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/up"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/down" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I took control of `surface` in the mainActivity and tried to draw a on it's borders a frame with width of 10px.

here the the mainActivity:

```
            public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
        GameView gv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.game_view);
            LinearLayout surface = new LinearLayout(this);
            surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
            gv= new GameView(this,surface);
            surface.addView(gv);
    }
}
```

here is the GameView class:

```
   public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        private boolean isRunning=false;
        private final long FPS=12;
        int PART_SIZE=6;

        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        Thread snakethread;
        LinearLayout view;


    public GameView(Context context,LinearLayout view) {
        super(context);
        this.view=view;
        this.a=new Arena();
        snakethread=new Thread(this);
        holder= getHolder();
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);                 
        this.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
                setRunning(true);
                snakethread.start();

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {



            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

                setRunning(false);

                while(true){
                    try {
                        snakethread.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    });
}

    public void run() {
        long stepPerSecond=1000/FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        Canvas c = null;
        try{
            c=this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (this.getHolder()) {
               c.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
               Paint p=new Paint();
               p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
               c.drawRect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getLeft()+10, view.getBottom(),p);
               c.drawRect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(),view.getRight(),view.getTop()+10,p);
               c.drawRect(view.getRight()-10, view.getTop(), view.getRight(),view.getBottom(),p);
               c.drawRect(view.getLeft(), view.getBottom()-10, view.getRight(),view.getBottom(),p);
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        finally{
            if(c!=null){
                this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is that the whole frame is approximately 6px under the view's Top,under where is should be. i mean that the `view.getTop()` and `view.getBottom()` return a worng result, a result that is bigger in approximately 6px then what it should be (if the view's top coordinate is x, then it return x+6).

Comment: Have you tried using getLocationInWindow() to get the View's Window location? It sounds very much like you're not taking the TitleBar into account (which yes, you have to do unless using Theme.NoTitleBar)

Comment: How can I get the bottom of the view with getLocationInWindow()?

Answer (score 2):

After Spend 2 Days I found the solution

```
int top = view.getTop(); 
int bottom = view.getBottom();  

// use these line instead of upper code 
 int statusBarHeight = (int) Math.ceil(25 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
 int top = (childTextView.getBottom()+childTextView.getHeight())-statusBarHeight ;
 int bottom = (childTextView.getTop()+childTextView.getHeight())-statusBarHeight ;
```

Comment: Hey man, I really thank you for trying. I have left this project aproximaltly 3  years ago, so i wouldnt know it what you i have solutioned works, but i really admire you trying to help and fix some post that have been posted more then 3 years ago. Hopfully it will help other on future problems